# Calculate the time a "SELECT query with huge result" takes in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, explain

I've been trying to calculate the time my queries take to complete in PostgreSQL.

I've written a bash script to issue a query using the following command "psql < query1.txt > /dev/null". However, the time measured using EXPLAIN is significantly different than the time measured using my bash script.

For one of the queries that returns 200,000+ rows, using the bash script, I got 13 seconds average elapsed time. But when I use EXPLAIN, the JSON file shows that it should take 218.735 milliseconds.

Is there is a way to find out where this extra time comes from?

I'm assuming that this happens because of the huge number of rows the from the query. Is there is a way to test a SELECT query without outputting its rows?

Note: I've also used a java application to measure the elapsed time. I got 1.2 seconds compared to 218.735 milliseconds with EXPLAIN command.

Can it be that EXPLAIN is not accurate?

Comment: The extra time is consumed by transferring the results to your `psql` frontend, and displaying them there.`EXPLAIN ANALYZE ...your query here...;` executes the query and ignores/throws away its results.

Comment: Use the psql command `\timing` to conveniently measure the time from the client side.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe \timing computes the time after the results are shown. So it counts the time to print all the results.